# WordPress website is showing white even debug mode is not working (Tiny File Manager Error: Cannot load configuration + white page)

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress website is showing white even debug mode is not working (Tiny File Manager Error: Cannot load configuration + white page)

1. disable the plugin not working
2. disable theme not working
3. change all the wp files but the results are the same
4. debug mode is not working
5. error log is not showing the exact error it shows the error in the index file which is empty

kindly share your experince

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the source code of the white page, it is probable the error was not visible.
2. If you mean "Failed To Load Resource", please check [How To Fix “Failed To Load Resource” Error In WordPress][1].
3. Assuming you have disabled all plugins and theme, there are two scenarios:

   - An edited WP file include a code like `die("...");`
   - Some internal server errors occurred in your server.